# How to clear form fields after a submit a button in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have this Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import ReportForm
from django.views import View
import spacy
import pdb
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')


class stopwordsremoval(FormView):
    template_name = 'report.html'
    form_class = ReportForm
    #pdb.set_trace()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        document1 = (form.cleaned_data.get('text'))

        return redirect('report_details', document1)
        return http.HttpResponseRedirect('')

class ReportDetails(View):
    def get(self,request,document1):
        word_lemma = []
        #pdb.set_trace()
        for word in (nlp(document1)):
            a = (word.is_stop, word.text)
            word_lemma.append(a)
        searchedData = (word_lemma)
        return render(request, 'report.html', {'naturallanguageprocessing': searchedData})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
import pdb

class ReportForm(forms.Form):
     text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5, 'cols': 100}))
```

it is creating the form and renders it below is the html code

html

```
  {% extends 'base.html' %}

 {% block content %}
 <h1>StopWordsRemoval</h1>
          <div>
          <form action = "" method = "post" >
               {% csrf_token %}

                  {{ form.as_p}}


          <button type="submit">stopwordsremoval</button>
               </div>



<div >
 <ul>

        <li>{{ naturallanguageprocessing }}</li>

   </ul>
       <a href="{% url 'stopwordsremoval' %}" </a>
       <style>
       div {
            width: 1000px;
            border: 5px solid green;
            padding: 10px;
             margin: 10px;
         }
          </style>
                </div>
                   </div>

    {% endblock %}
```

my problem is while clicking button form will display we can enter input and get output at same place but button remain same form will invisible.my requirement is everything should be same only when i click button it output will display below as well as form should remain same with input.

Comment: Please format your Views.py file correctly. form_valid method contains two returns.